# how to remove default background color for selected item in navbar for bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have implemented a navbar using bootstrap 3. After selecting the list in the navbar white color background is appearing for the active link. How should I remove that.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9d43.png)

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
                      <li class="active"><a  href="#" data-tab='main'>Home</a></li>
                      <li><a  href="#aboutus" data-tab="aboutus">About</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#gallery" data-tab="gallery">Gallery </a></li>
                      <li><a href="#career"  data-tab="career">career</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Can you add the CSS you got so far? simple solution would be to just remove the active class from li?

Comment: That source code can't reproduce problem. Can you add source code that reproduce problem?

Comment: Simply add transparent background to you .active class in you CSS, be aware your custom imported CSS must after bootstrap library, or set !important to your .active class.

Answer (score 3):

try this css code:

```
#nav .active, #nav > li > a:focus{
    background: transparent;
}
```

i hope it work for you.

Comment: Reza ghasemi it's not working. I have updated code. kidly look into it and let me know https://codepen.io/vsandeep2516/pen/XWbzPVa

Comment: @here kindly help me to find this solution

Answer (score 1):

The white background is set on hover and on focus, so you will need a extra rule for when its beeing focused.

```
.nav > li > a:focus, .nav > li > a:hover {
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: There's a flash of background when de-selecting the nav fields. Add this as well:
`.nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:hover, .nav .open > a:focus { background: none !important}`;